# How do you configure IP Restriction on Web App to allow traffic only through the application gateway?

Tags: azure

I need to add some security to my backend pool webapps. I know you can use IP Restrictions, To allow access only via the application gateway i need to enter an IP Address but it only allows me to put a range in the IP Restriction of the Web app and I cannot use the public IP or DNS of the gateway. Can anyone advise on how to allow traffic to the web apps only via the app gateway

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the underlying IIS to only accept traffic from some IP addresses.

You can find out this and a bunch of other stuff at http://microsoftazurewebsitescheatsheet.info.

In this case we can add the following section to web.config to only allow traffic from 123.456.0.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
        <add allowed="true" ipAddress="123.456.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>
      </ipSecurity>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: is there not a way of doing this via IP Restriction in the Web app ?

Comment: Ahh, haha I had not seen that :D You can totally do that there too. You'll have to use the app gateway's public IP I think.

Comment: You can try to specify the "range" as 123.123.123.123/32 so it's only the one IP address